# Why second channel not receiving data from previous channel

Tags: go

I'm doing my first steps with go channels, and tried to write the below code, where I want to do the following with goroutine that is reading from a given csv file, emit the read record to another channel which is adding the same record to another csv file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func failOnError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error:", err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
func main() {
    read := make(chan Data)
    go func(input_file string) {
        var data Data

        fr, err := os.Open(input_file)
        failOnError(err)
        defer fr.Close()
        r := csv.NewReader(fr)
        rows, err := r.ReadAll()
        failOnError(err)
        data.header = rows[0]
        for _, row := range rows[1:] {
            data.lines = append(data.lines, Person{
                Firstname: row[0],
                Lastname:  row[1],
                Address: &Address{
                    City:  row[2],
                    State: row[3],
                },
            })
        }

        peopleJson, _ := json.Marshal(data.lines)
        fmt.Println(string(peopleJson))   // This is working smoothly

        read <- data
    }("people.csv")

    csvOut, err := os.Create("resultsfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to open output")
    }

    out := make(chan int)
    select {
    case data := <-read:
        go func(data Data) {
            println("data received")     // <-- Not show up
            w := csv.NewWriter(csvOut)
            defer csvOut.Close()
            // handle header
            data.header = append(data.header, "score")
            if err = w.Write(data.header); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            /*
                hanlde data
            */
            w.Flush()
            out <- 0
        }(data)
    case _ = <-out:
        println("done")
    }

}

type Person struct {
    Firstname string   `json:"firstname"` // JSON annotation will allow for easy printing to JSON after it had been loaded
    Lastname  string   `json:"lastname"`
    Address   *Address `json:"address,omitempty"`
}

type Address struct {
    City  string `json:"city"`
    State string `json:"state"`
}

type Data struct {
    header []string
    lines  []Person
}
```

my code failed, with no error and did not show the `data received`  note

`people.csv` file is:

```
First,Last,City,State
Nic,Raboy,San Francisco,CA
Maria,Raboy,Dublin,CA
Hasan,yousef, Jordan, ZA
```

And the output i got is:

```sh
[Running] go run "d:\goplay\csv.go"
[{"firstname":"Nic","lastname":"Raboy","address":{"city":"San Francisco","state":"CA"}},{"firstname":"Maria","lastname":"Raboy","address":{"city":"Dublin","state":"CA"}},{"firstname":"Hasan","lastname":"yousef","address":{"city":" Jordan","state":" ZA"}}]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.233 seconds
```

Comment: thanks for the mvp code, but an example of the people.csv would also be required to run it

Comment: @DanielFarrell question updated with the csv file and terminal output

Comment: Awesome, I can improve my answer.  Thanks

Comment: your program exits before the routine ends. you need an additional <-out right after it.

Comment: see something like https://play.golang.org/p/Hkk22dorXRs

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon but what if I still need to use goroutine in the writing stage how can I pass the returned result from the first goroutine to the second one, and ensure  it is working as required

Comment: you can try to use a channel like you did. You can also use a waitgroup. https://play.golang.org/p/GlbdKVyENJF

Comment: with a chan https://play.golang.org/p/v8ICp2QcGTQ

Comment: Thanks a lot @mh-cbon i learned a lot from both codes, appreciated

Comment: cool! I want to add a question. What happens if you process a 40GB file on a xsmall instance ? = )

Comment: @mh-cbon I'm doing my first steps with go, just started this Sunday :) mmm, you tell me, what could happen another opportunity to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tthe problem is this:

```
    select {
    case data := <-read:
        go func(data Data) {
```

The `select` is the last thing in the `main` function.   When it reads `data` from `read`, it starts a goroutine in the background to process it.  The `main` function then ends and, thus, the program exits.

Go does not automatically wait for goroutines.  It's up to you to use "done" channels or whatever to synchronize between them.

You essentially have a pipeline that *conceptually* looks something like this:

```
                                         ----> process -> write to `out`
                                        /
start --> main file waits  data on `read` *or* wait for `out` -> done
       \
        ---> CSV reads all lines and outputs data to `read`
```

Because you actually only send one message over the channel, you don't really need a `select`, or a `loop`.  You just neeed to wait for the data, process it , and have `main` wait for the completion:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func failOnError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error:", err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
func main() {
    read := make(chan Data)
    go func(input_file string) {
        var data Data

        fr, err := os.Open(input_file)
        failOnError(err)
        defer fr.Close()
        r := csv.NewReader(fr)
        rows, err := r.ReadAll()
        failOnError(err)
        data.header = rows[0]
        for _, row := range rows[1:] {
            data.lines = append(data.lines, Person{
                Firstname: row[0],
                Lastname:  row[1],
                Address: &Address{
                    City:  row[2],
                    State: row[3],
                },
            })
        }

        peopleJson, _ := json.Marshal(data.lines)
        fmt.Println(string(peopleJson)) // This is working smoothly

        read <- data
    }("people.csv")

    csvOut, err := os.Create("resultsfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to open output")
    }

    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        data := <-read
        println("data received") // <-- Not show up
        w := csv.NewWriter(csvOut)
        defer csvOut.Close()
        // handle header
        data.header = append(data.header, "score")
        if err = w.Write(data.header); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        /*
           hanlde data
        */
        w.Flush()
        out <- 0
    }()

    <-out
    println("done")
}

type Person struct {
    Firstname string   `json:"firstname"` // JSON annotation will allow for easy printing to JSON after it had been loaded
    Lastname  string   `json:"lastname"`
    Address   *Address `json:"address,omitempty"`
}

type Address struct {
    City  string `json:"city"`
    State string `json:"state"`
}

type Data struct {
    header []string
    lines  []Person
}
```

The OP asks,

> Is there a way to receive input from previous channels without select and at same time ensure the program is not exit before finishing what is required? – Hasan A Yousef 1 min ago

All of your channels as written pass exactly one message, which means that once you read the channel *once*, you can assume the writer is complete.  So with your use of the `out` channel, you already achieve this.

If you had an *unknown* number of sends to the channel, you could use the builtin `close` functionality to achieve this:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  send := make(chan int)
  result := make(chan int)
  go func() {
    sum := 0
    for i := range send {
      sum += i
    }
    result <- sum
  }()
  for _, x := range []int{1,2,3}  {
    send <- x
  }
  close(send)
  fmt.Println("Sum is: ", <-result)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to receive input from previous channels without `select` and at same time ensure the program is not exit before finishing what is required?

Comment: once I removed the `go` from the second function, I got `data received
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main.func2(0xc000006028, 0xc00008fe80, 0xc0000141e0, 0xc0000c2000, 0x5, 0x8, 0xc0000a8000, 0x3, 0x4)
 d:/goplay/csv.go:67 +0x286
main.main()
 d:/goplay/csv.go:68 +0x25d
exit status 2`

Comment: yeah, that was dumb of me.  I missed the use of `out` channel there, so I removed that.  I'm trying to improve my answer for you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, also I learned a lot from the comments.